# Unable to request resources using http.send

Tags: open-policy-agent

When I run the following code:

```
data := response {
    response := http.send({
        "method" : "GET",
        "url": "https://httpbin.org/status/200"
    })
}
```

I get this error:

> **1 error occurred: policy.rego:4: rego_type_error: unsafe built-in function calls in expression: http.send**

Im using the rego play to run that policy. https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/iqK8Zt5L62

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that is specific to the playground, as allowing arbitrary HTTP requests to be sent from there could potentially be misused. Your rule should work fine in any other context.